# Reload Screen on goBack react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Lets assume there are two screens in a stack navigator:

First_Screen -> Second_Screen

How can we refresh/reload previous screen when returning to it by calling this.props.navigation.goBack()?

I am using the below react-native and react-navigation versions:

```
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
```

I have tried the below,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      () => {
        this.props.fetchData();
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
  }
```

But did not get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, it's working fine

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", async () => {
      const response = await apiCall();
    });

      return unsubscribe;
    }, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it will work

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.onFocusCall = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      this.apiCall();
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onFocusCall.remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using react-navigation 5x you need to update the listener to following

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData();
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'focus',
      () => {
        this.props.fetchData();
      }
    );
  }
```

docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/