# React Native tab navigator re-render screen component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Here is my code which implements a simple tab navigator. In one of the screens I need to make a request to an API and update the states every time the screen is selected by user via the tab navigator. As shown below the `componentDidMount` is not executed after first time (Second attempt fails on execution).

```
export default class UserAccount extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            sample:''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {

       // Api fetch 
       // ...

       await this.setState({sample: api.response})

    }

    render() {
        return (
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

And the tab navigator is:

```
<Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <MaterialIcons name="home" color={focused ? activeTintLabelColor : inactiveTintLabelColor} size={23} />
        ),
    }} name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <FontAwesome5 name="wallet" color={focused ? activeTintLabelColor : inactiveTintLabelColor} size={20} />
        )
    }} name="Wallets" component={UserWallets} />
    
</Tab.Navigator>
```

What should I do to let the tab navigator re-renders the screen component which causes the execution of `componentDidMount`?

Regards.

Comment: This answer will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63610063/3784556

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-navigation: Detect when screen, tabbar is activated / appear / focus / blur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290818/react-navigation-detect-when-screen-tabbar-is-activated-appear-focus-blu)

Comment: @SaachiTech    The first link solved the problem. Thanks.